# Parallels - Can I have a keyboard shortcut for the context-menu key found on Wintel hardware?

Tags: keyboard, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop, shortcut-menu

On a lot of Windows keyboards there's a key to the right of the spacebar that brings up the context-menu (right-click menu) in applications (I'm running Win7). I can't seem to find a way to map this function to the VM's keyboard in Parallels. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 8):

*For Bootcamp I'm using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) app as a way to remap standard Windows keyboard switch combination to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.*

I've just tried to remap right command key of my Apple Aluminum keyboard to become Context menu key and it works with editing AutoHotkey.aht configuration file  and adding

> RWin::AppsKey

as a key binding. You may read more on remapping with AutoHotKey [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm). And [here is a list](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) of key names.

Also, in Windows, <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> should act as a context menu shortcut but I can't attest since my F10 key is not working and I'm too lazy to boot into Windows again and remap it just to test it.)

Comment: +1 for the Shift + F10. That seems to work for the most part, depending on what control has focus. Thanks.

Comment: Shift + F10 works great!